# phpDocumentor crashing when using graphviz

Tags: graphviz, phpdoc

I just managed to get "dot" installed correctly, per a warning in phpDocumentor.  Now when I try to build my docs, however, I am getting the exception:

```
  [phpDocumentor\GraphViz\Exception]
  An error occurred while creating the graph; GraphViz returned: Format: "svg" not recognized. Use one of:
```

Does anyone know how to get past this?  The command I am running is:

```
php phpdoc.php -c mypath/phpdoc.dist.xml -p
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, running `sudo dot -c` fixed it for me.